# reactjs - animate single DOM element without re-rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following react component:

```
return(
            <div className="project-page">
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h1>{currentProject.title}</h1>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
                <div className="container ">
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
                        <div className="project-image-container"> 
                            <img src={currentProject.image} alt="Project Image" />
                        </div>
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>  
                    .....
```

I'm using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to animate image which works fine on components' initial load. However animation doesn't work when component gets updated with new dataset/image.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animating updated content is not currently supported in react. Currently, `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` can only animate components that are being added or removed.

However it is possible to make react think that a component has been removed or added. React relies on the `key` attribute to uniquely identify child components.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
return(
    var key = projectId;

    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup key={key} transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
          <div className="project-image-container"> 
               <img src={currentProject.image} alt="Project Image" />
          </div>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

In this example, you must pass unique `id` or any other value. It doesn't even need to be unique. You just need to update it with any value on component update.

This [blog](http://unitstep.net/blog/2015/03/03/using-react-animations-to-transition-between-ui-states/) covers this topic in more depth.